# Is apache thrift 0.18.0 compatible with openssl 3.0?

Tags: openssl, thrift

I did a lot of searches but couldn't find any sources about this topic. I then tried with some API search tools but got confusingly different answers. Same question "Is apache thrift 0.18.0 compatible with openssl 3.0?" for sourcegraph and google bard:

From sourcegraph:

> Based on the README.md and code snippets from the apache/thrift repository, Apache Thrift 0.18.0 does not appear to be directly compatible with OpenSSL 3.0:
>
> - The 0.18.0 release notes and changelog don't mention OpenSSL 3.0 support.
> - The build scripts and Dockerfiles in 0.18.0 still install OpenSSL 1.0.x or 1.1.x versions, not 3.0.
> - The Thrift code initializes OpenSSL in a way that expects older 1.x versions.
> - There are no clear references to OpenSSL 3.0 compatibility in the provided 0.18.0 code snippets.
>
> So in summary, OpenSSL 3.0 compatibility likely came later, after the 0.18.0 release, based on the context from apache/thrift. The 0.18.0 code still relies on older OpenSSL initialization and behavior. Direct OpenSSL 3.0 support is not indicated in the Thrift 0.18.0 files. The version number alone does not guarantee compatibility.

From google bard:

> Yes, Apache Thrift 0.18.0 is compatible with OpenSSL 3.0. In fact, it
> is the most recent version of Apache Thrift and is the recommended
> version for use with OpenSSL 3.0.
>
> Here is a quote from the Apache Thrift documentation:
> https://thrift.apache.org/lib/cpp.html:
>
> "Thrift uses the OpenSSL library for its TLS implementation. The
> minimum required version of OpenSSL is 1.0.2, but we recommend using
> the latest version of OpenSSL."
>
> If you are using OpenSSL 3.0 with Apache Thrift 0.18.0, you should not
> experience any compatibility issues.
>
> However, it is important to note that OpenSSL 3.0 is a major revision
> of OpenSSL and there may be some compatibility issues with older
> versions of Thrift. If you are using an older version of Thrift, you
> may need to upgrade to a newer version in order to use OpenSSL 3.0.

Comment: I guess the real question you want to ask is "are the language bindings I plan to use capable to use a certain SSL/TLS version?" Thrift supports 20+ target languages and it is rather hard to make a defintive statement of that kind that is true for every single one at the same time. Futhermore your use case does not reveal why it has to be OpenSSL? It might be totally obvious to you, but not to somebody else, so adding that bit of information might help to get great answers.